# Radio button value not stored in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, database

I created a radio button in which when user click on yes value then text box is shown to user otherwise they remain  hide.
My question when user select yes then I am able to store yes value in sql but when user click on no value that value is not stored in datbase

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
     $('input[name="yeshave"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
           $('#textboxes').show();
        } else {
           $('#textboxes').hide();
        }
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

no radio button code:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Do you haver passport:</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="yeshave" value="yes"> Yes</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="yeshave" value="no"> No</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

SQL code is:

```php
if(isset($_POST['yeshave']))
{
    $selectedValue=$_POST['yeshave'];
}



 $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, image,passport_no,dateofissue,dateofexpiry,placeofissue, having_passport ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$image','".$passno."','".$doi."','".$doe."','".$poi."','".$selectedValue."')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

Comment: What is the data type of the field having_passport in your database??

Comment: Why not do `$selectedValue= (!empty($_POST['yeshave'])) : 1 : 0;`? Is `having_passport` a tinyint?

Comment: @saty having_passport have varchar data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set check one of them. Try with -

```
$selectedValue = isset($_POST['yeshave']) ? $_POST['yeshave'] : 'no';
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="yeshave"]').on('click', function() {
        $('#textboxes').toggle($(this).val() == 'yes');
    });
});
```

In PHP:

```
$selectedValue = $_POST['yeshave'] ? $_POST['yeshave'] : 'no';
```

1. You don't need `$(function()` inside `ready`
2. Use `toggle` to hide/show `#textboxes`
3. In PHP, check if value is present, if not use default `no`

Comment: ur toggle is gud for that u score 10 marks frm my side but still when i select no this entry not going to database

Comment: @rupesharora DId you check if `no` is `POST`ed on server

Comment: Can u plz provide me ur maid id then i will send u the source code

Comment: @rupesharora print `$_POST` on server and check `no`. Check if `no` is printed inside `yeshave`